# Get just the first row for each company

Tags: oracle

I have this

```
Select DISTINCT  p.productname, c.companyname,od.productID,
(SELECT
    sum( quantity )
FROM orderdetails where productID=p.ProductID) as total
from 
customers c inner join orders o on
c.customerid=o.customerid inner join orderdetails od on
o.orderid=od.orderid inner join products p on
od.productid=p.productid

order by c.companyname, total DESC
```

and that returns me
[image: return]
I need it to only return the row of the highest total for each companyname
[image: I WANT JUST THE MARKED ONES]

Comment: You have mistankenly tagged two different DBMS, MySQL and Oracle. Which are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top n records for each group of grouped results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results)

Comment: Please note that many sites block links, and many participants here refuse to open links for the same security reason others block them. Nothing prevents you from pasting that content directly into your question.  Doing so is much appreciated by all, and will generally be more conducive to receiving a positive response.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Max property to get the maximum total.

```
MAX(aggregate_expression)
FROM tables
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use your current query (if you're satisfied with it) as a "source" (either a CTE - as in my example, or a subquery) for ranking rows per `TOTAL` column value for each `COMPANYNAME`, and then return the highest ranked rows.

```
WITH
   your_query
   AS
      (SELECT DISTINCT p.productname,
                       c.companyname,
                       od.productID,
                       (SELECT SUM (quantity)
                          FROM orderdetails
                         WHERE productID = p.ProductID) AS total
         FROM customers c
              INNER JOIN orders o ON c.customerid = o.customerid
              INNER JOIN orderdetails od ON o.orderid = od.orderid
              INNER JOIN products p ON od.productid = p.productid),
   temp
   AS
      -- rank TOTAL values per each COMPANYNAME
      (SELECT productname,
              companyname,
              productid,
              total,
              RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY companyname ORDER BY total DESC) rnk
         FROM your_query)
  -- finally, return rows whose TOTAL ranks as 1st (in descending order)         
  SELECT productname,
         companyname,
         productid,
         total
    FROM temp
   WHERE rnk = 1
ORDER BY companyname
```